# How to open db.dump from Ubuntu on Windows 7

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, ubuntu, dump

Is there a way how to open a database .dump file from Ubuntu on Windows 7 in PostgreSQL?
I have created an empty database in PgAdmin 3 and then tried to restore it with the db.dump but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you created the file using pg_dump or pg_dumpall, then you can restore it by using the

```
psql -f <file name>
```

if it's from pg_dumpall or

```
psql -f <file name> <database name>
```

if it's from pg_dump.